# How to change the values dynamically in a grid

Tags: dynamic, grid-layouts

I am trying to write a function which creates a `Grid` which has no value in the starting and when some value is passed to it, it should show that value in that `Grid` dynamically. But it is not changing it dynamically.

The two user defined functions are

```
createGrid[rows_, column_] := (list = {}; 
  For[i = 1, i <= rows,i++, (individualColumns = {}; 
  For[j = 1, j <= column,j++, (Subscript[e,i, j]="";individualColumns = Append[individualColumns,Subscript[e,i, j]];)]; 
list = Append[list, individualColumns];)]; layoutGrid[list])
```

This createGrid function generates null values which is then passed to user defined function layoutGrid.

```
 layoutGrid[list_] := 
Panel[Grid[list, Background -> LightBlue, Spacings -> {0, 0}, ItemSize -> {0, 0},   Alignment -> {Center, Center}],ImageSize -> {780, 480}, Background -> LightBlue]
```

I am calling the createGrid function by passing 20 rows and 20 columns as arguments.

```
Dynamic[createGrid[20,20]]
```

It creates the `Grid` having 20 rows and 20 columns having no value.

In createGrid function, variable Subscript[e,i,j], i defines the row number and j defines the column number

After building the empty `Grid`,when I am assigning some value to Subscript[e,1,2] like

```
Subscript[e,1,2]=10;
```

It does not show in the `Grid` dynamically. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do :

```
alist = ConstantArray["", {20, 20}];

Dynamic@Panel[ Grid[alist, Background -> LightBlue, Spacings -> {1, 1}, 
  ItemSize -> {0, 0}, Alignment -> {Center, Center}], 
  ImageSize -> {780, 480}, Background -> LightBlue]

alist[[1, 2]] = 10;
alist[[3]] = ConstantArray[3.14, {20}];
alist[[4, 2]] = 2.71;
alist[[4, 3]] = SpanFromLeft;
alist[[4, 4]] = 2.71;
alist[[4, 5]] = 2.71;
```

[image: grid]

Comment: Thank you alot!for your replyBut if I assign the `SpanFromLeft` to the alist[[1,2]] then spanning is not working

Comment: @subbu It seems to be working fine, please see edit.